# Blank page (except index.html) with Angular 4 in Tomcat environment

Tags: angular, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I built the angular app with the following command:

```
ng build --prod --aot --output-hashing=none --base-href=/sample/
```

After that, copied all the files inside dist folder to tomcat's webapp folder.
Accessing index.html went ok, however when trying to change to another page it will return 404 error.

What have I missed?

Comment: Do you have any routing in your project ?

Comment: Does your application run fine in dev target `ng build`?

Comment: @trichetriche yes I do. Anything needs to be added / modified?

Comment: @AmitChigadani I can run the site smoothly in dev

Comment: Could you try, when you define the routerModule, to do so `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true })` ?

Comment: @trichetriche it still doesn't work

Comment: you chanded base href and you might need to set that in your index.html or at the time of bootstraping of application `  <base href="/sample/">`.

Comment: @AniruddhaDas I already did that, I can access the index.html but not for other pages

Comment: I know there is a variable that needs to be set so the server will not try to reed the header and it will let angular handle it. Can't remember what it was. If you don't set you will have to use # for new url's. Hope this is helpful

Comment: @OreoFanatics do you see any errors on browser console?

Comment: @AmitChigadani No. However I noticed in the dist folder is that there is only an index.html page and not the other page. Is that how it supposed to be?

Comment: @OreoFanatics In your question you said you copied all the files from dist folder. Now you say you only have index.html. There should be at least main.bundle and vendor.bundle files along with any other file types which were not recognized by angular during compilation. And did you build your application in dev? How does that look?

Comment: @AmitChigadani yes indeed I copied all the files in dist folder so main.bundle and vendor.bundle are included. I did not know if the other pages (the html, ts, etc) files should also be in the dist folder because I don't see it. And I build this in dev.

Comment: @OreoFanatics Can you check your index.html and see where `<base href="/">` is pointing?

Comment: @AmitChigadani it is pointing to `"/sample/"`. Since I am using Angular router also to navigate between pages I set from the NavBar, does it perhaps require different / additional deployment setup?

Comment: Did you find any useful solutions? I copied content of dist folder to resources/static folder. It runs well but when I deploy war file to remote I only get a blank page instead of index.html